# Хочу сделать ограничение(if) в шаблоне для авторизованных пользователей через социальные сети

Tags: django, jinja2, django-allauth

Такая проблема. Хочу чтобы пользователь, когда находится на странице профиля, если он авторизовался через Google, к примеру, не мог видеть кнопку смены пароля, а также не мог перейти на страницу смены пароля.. Я вот не знаю как это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для пользователя, проверяете наличие связанной с его записью `User` объекта, связанного с `Provider` ([список провайдеров](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html)).

Примерно должно выглядеть так

```
has_linked_account = SocialAccount.objects.filter(user=request.user, provider="<provider_name>")
```

А ограничить доступ к контенту -  `has_permission` или иные способо, которые вы уже использовали

[Модели allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/models.py)